# Brute force model selection with Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a feature matrix (X_train_balanced) and a target vector (y_train_balanced) for a classification task (3 classes). To perform model selection and hyperparameter tuning, I intend to use sklearn's GridsearchCV on each of the models I want to compare (LR, SVC, RF and KNN).

My idea is then to compare the best result for each model yielded from the GridsearchCV to select the best model.

I would like to know if this approach makes sense and if the code I developed for the task is correct.

> ## Model search space
>
> ```
> models = {
>         'LogisticRegression'     : LogisticRegression(),
>         'SVM'                    : SVC(),
>         'RandomForestClassifier' : RandomForestClassifier(),
>         'KNN'                    : KNeighborsClassifier()}
> ```
>
> ## Hyperparameter search space
>
> ```
> hyper = {
>         
>         'LogisticRegression':{
>                                     'penalty'     : ['l2'],
>                                     'C'           : np.logspace(0, 4, 10),
>                                     'solver'      : ['lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'saga'],
>                                     'class_weight': ['balanced'],
>                                     'random_state': [0]},
>         
>         'SVM':{
>                                     'C'           : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
>                                     'gamma'       : [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001],
>                                     'kernel'      : ['rbf', 'linear'],
>                                     'class_weight': ['balanced'],
>                                     'random_state': [0]},
>         
>         'RandomForestClassifier':{
>                                     'max_depth': [2, 3, 4],
>                                     'max_features': [2, 3, 4, 'auto', 'sqrt'],
>                                     'n_estimators': [10, 100, 500, 1000],
>                                     'class_weight': ['balanced'],
>                                     'random_state': [0]},
>        
>         'KNN':{
>                                     'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 15, 20],
>                                     'weights': ['uniform', 'distance']}
>                               
>                               
>     }
> ```
>
> ## Perform cross-validation for each model
>
> ```
> for model_name in models.keys():
>
>   # Model selection
>   clf    = models[model_name]
>   params = hyper[model_name]
>
>   # Pipeline (standarization + classifier)
>   pipe = Pipeline([ ( 'scaler', StandardScaler() ), ( 'clf', clf ) ])
>  
>   # Gridsearch cross-validation
>   grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = clf, param_grid = params, cv = 5, return_train_score = True)
>   grid.fit(X_train_balanced, y_train_balanced)
>
>   # Gridsearch cross-validation results
>   best_param                  = grid.best_params_
>   best_param_test_score_mean  = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][grid.best_index_]
>   best_param_test_score_std   = grid.cv_results_['std_test_score'][grid.best_index_]
>   best_param_train_score_mean = grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score'][grid.best_index_]
>   best_param_train_score_std  = grid.cv_results_['std_train_score'][grid.best_index_]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, as long as you have the required imports:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

and I would say it also makes sense.

At the end of your code, you can add the lines

```
print(best_param)
print(grid.best_estimator_)
```

to get the best parameters and the best performing estimator. I ran your code with these changes and the output for the dataset I tested it with for instance is:

```
{'n_neighbors': 15, 'weights': 'uniform'}
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
                     metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=15, p=2,
                     weights='uniform')
```

Comment: Hey Kim, thanks for answering. With respect to your last sentence, if I am not wrong, I should run the code and then use the  `grid.best_estimator_` model, however, this model for me will be different than the one you got, as we considered different datasets. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh yes, you will probably have a different model. I just used some dataset for testing the code from sklearn. You are right.